# Running Websphere Liberty as a windows service

Tags: websphere-liberty

I know that full Websphere has a utility that allowed you to create a windows service to start and stop a server.  But i have not seen anything like that for liberty.

Do i use a 3rd party bridge like http://nssm.cc ? or is there another way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no builtin integration with Windows service, so you'll have to find a third party solution.

I have no experience with them, but you might also look at [Java Service Launcher](http://jslwin.sourceforge.net/) or [Java Service Wrapper](http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.com/doc/english/introduction.html).

Answer (score 1):

Add `WAS` as a windows service (with startup type set to automatically)
Open `Command Prompt` with Administrator rights (*Run as Administrator*), then use following command:

```
sc create WASLibertyV85 binPath="C:\IBM\WebSphere\Liberty\bin\server.bat start simpleServer" DisplayName="IBM WebSphere Liberty V8.5" start=auto
```

where "simpleServer" is the name of the server.

```
C:\Users\Administrator>sc create WASLibertyV85 binPath="C:\IBM\WebSphere\Liberty\bin\server.bat start simpleServer" DisplayName="IBM WebSphere
Liberty V8.5" start=auto

[SC] CreateService SUCCESS
```

Note: WAS Liberty server can be started and stopped using the following commands:

To start it: `C:\IBM\WebSphere\Liberty\bin\server.bat start simpleServer`
To stop it: `C:\IBM\WebSphere\Liberty\bin\server.bat stop simpleServer`

ATTENTION:

When Service is started manually (sc start WASLibertyV85) or thru Service interface following problems "can" appear. This error does not impact the server to start.

```
C:\Users\Administrator>sc start WASLibertyV85

[SC] StartService FAILED 1053:
```

The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion.

Comment: I have two servers (applications) hosted on the one Liberty installation. How can we register both applications as a service on the windows servers?

Answer (score 1):

In WebSphere Liberty in 17.0.0.1, there is a new set of options in the "server" command.

```
server  registerWinService  <server name>
server  unregisterWinService  <server name>
server  startWinService  <server name>
server  stopWinService  <server name>
```

The services can also start and stop via the Windows services control panel.

Answer (score 0):

I am using below third party tool..

http://sourceforge.net/projects/yajsw/files/yajsw/yajsw-stable-11.07/