# How to forcefully stop websphere liberty server in windows 7

Tags: server, websphere-liberty, java-server

Suddenly Websphere server is automatically started.

I stop many times but started again automatically.

Even I removed project from the web sphere and removed websphere from the project and Again add for the same.. But still I it is starting.

I also run the below command,

```
Server stop server_name
```

below Message is showing

```
Stopping server server_name
```

So it is not stoping. How to stop forcefully? or Kill existing process?

Comment: In WebSphere Liberty 17.0.0.1, this function is available https://stackoverflow.com/a/44762307/4825911

Comment: In WebSphere Liberty 17.0.0.1, this function is available https://stackoverflow.com/a/44762307/4825911

Answer (score 3):

Your question doesn't state what OS you're running on, but Liberty doesn't currently ship with any means to automatically start the server (like a Windows service), so when you say "started again automatically", it is more likely that the server is never shutdown.  Liberty runs as a process that can be killed and the process id can be determined by looking at the messages.log file in the server logs directory. The preamble of the file will contain a line like this:

```
process = 11488@YourHostName
```

Depending on the OS you're running on, you can use the kill command (Linux or MacOS), or the Windows Task manager to end the process.  When you restart the server, you may want to specify the --clean option like this:

```
server start defaultServer --clean
```

Comment: Last I knew, the server will automatically detect that it was not stopped cleanly, and it will automatically clean itself when you next restart even without the `--clean` option (as [documented](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEQTP_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.doc/ae/rwlp_command_server.html), the `--clean` option should typically not be used).

Comment: You're right, we can detect under certain circumstances that a clean start is needed.  Given the confusion of the original question, that's no harm in issuing the --clean explicitly.  The alternative would be to kill the server, attempt to start it normally and if that fails, kill it again and restart with clean.