# How to Run WAS Liberty Core server as a Background Service in Windows

Tags: windows, websphere, websphere-liberty, maximo-anywhere

We have installed WAS Liberty Core 8.5.5 to run Maximo anywhere mobile applications.

If we start the server from CMD then we are able to access worklight console and maximo anywhere apps.

Command we are using to start the server.

> server start server1

But once we closed the CMD window the server stops automatically.

Any workaround to run the server as a background Service ?

Also we need info on how to add WAS Liberty server to Windows startup service so that it will start automatically on system restart.

Thanks,

Ajay

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The feature to setup a proper windows service is not available in Websphere Liberty 8.5.5.x.

You can use sc.exe to create a service linked to the server executable, but it won't behave correctly i.e. it won't respond correctly to the commands from the services application. As an example, you will be able to start the service and the server will run, but then you will see an error saying the service did not respond in a timely fashion.

According to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18706076/running-websphere-liberty-as-a-windows-service) the proper functionality, as described in the other answer, only became available around version 17.0.0.1.

Hope that helps,

John

Comment: Thank you John. I have created service using SC.exe and it is working fine.

Answer (score 1):

You can run Liberty as a Windows service:

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEQTP_liberty/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.doc/ae/twlp_setup_new_server_winserv.html

> bin\server registerWinService *serverName*
>
> bin\server startWinService *serverName*
>
> bin\server stopWinService *serverName*

Of course "net stop/net start" or services.msc can be used instead of startWinService/stopWinService

Comment: We are using WAS_Liberty_Core_V8.5.5. 
Do we have that options in 8.5.5? 
I am getting below error while executing bin\server registerWinService serverName

"unknown option registerWinService"